# What are the internal optimizations for reusing UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, uitableview

When iOS reuses tableview cells, if the content is the same is the cell still refreshed? That is, if we call tableview.reloadData() is the content of the cell written even if that content is identical?

Further questions - How is this effected if the data is more complicated, for example the size of the cell is different?

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon what you’re doing inside `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`, but assuming you’re not doing anything extraordinary there, the cost of reloading the cell is generally fairly modest. That having been said, we don’t do `reloadData` unless we have to (e.g. if you need to reload a single row, we use [`reloadRows(at:with:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614935-reloadrows); if inserting a row, we use [`insertRows(at:with:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614879-insertrows); if you need to reload a single section, we use [`reloadSections(_:with:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614954-reloadsections); etc.). Don’t call `reloadData` unnecessarily or with any great frequency.